# sending multiple params via email

Tags: html, email, grails

Hi guys I'm trying do a user change password method via email and my current code is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Hello ${userInstance.user.username}, your password will be set to ${userInstance.new_pass} to finalise your password request, please click the link below.</p>
    <h2><g:link controller="reset" action="reset" params="[id:userInstance.user.id]" absolute="true">Please change my password</g:link></h2>
</body>
```

The current link only sends the user ID param to my method in grails. I wish to send the password as a parameter too! What is a possible solution to send userInstance.new_pass via this link?

p.s. I'm using grails mail plugin.

Comment: Sending passwords in E-Mails is very, very bad practice security-wise. See this for details: [Is sending password to user email secure?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17979)

Comment: ya it is true.. better to send link of updation in the mail

Comment: I do know it's a bad practice, I'm doing this as a temporary quick fix until a proper way is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
 <g:link controller="reset" action="reset" params="[id:userInstance.user.id;password:userInstance.user.password]" absolute="true">Please change my password</g:link>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work .._grails_app_views_reset__resetMail_gsp: 22: expecting ']', found ':' @ line 22, column 271. :userInstance.user.id;password:userInsta ^ 1 error

Comment: Use `,` instead of `;` - that's a Groovy list syntax.